# Gmail API - getting User Name, Account open date and Location

Tags: email, gmail-api

Im trying to develop an application that accesses a user gmail account and provides them with some statistics about the account.

What is the best way to get the following information using the APIs?

1. User's Name (First and Last). [Users:getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile) is very limited.
2. When was the account opened. (I can find the "oldest" mail in the mailbox but that does not necessarily equate with the date on which the account was opened).
3. How to get sender's IP (so I can infer the location - using another geo API)
4. Location of user when they access the account (or alternatively their IP).
5. Is there a way to sort the results from list operations (e.g. gmail.users.messages.list)

Thanks!

Comment: You can get information of when account was opened from Gmail UI. Go to settings->Forwarding and POP/IMAP->POP Download:Status: POP is enabled for all mail that has arrived since 20/01/2008 this is the date when account is created. I dont think you can get this info from Gmail API.

Comment: You can list messages with in particular dates using query parameter in messages.list and here is the link for the valid values you can give to query https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en&ref_topic=3394914

Comment: Using dates as part of the query is only a last resort if I can't list the messages in reverse order. Instead of getting the first message in the inbox in a single query I'll need ~20 queries (Log (period) ).